# where to add htaccess file in angular 4 cli project to add rewrite rules?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have completed angular project. now i want to change some url format force fully using htaccess file.so where should i put htaccess file?
I have tried everywhere like belows path:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/GreatColoradoHomes
/opt/lampp/htdocs/GreatColoradoHomes/src
/opt/lampp/htdocs/GreatColoradoHomes/src/app
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

there is answer in github [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4607#issuecomment-279052589)

> Put .htaccess in src folder (final path for is `src/.htaccess`)
>
> Add it to `angular-cli.json` in the assets array (like favicon.ico).
>
> Have something similar to this:
>   
>     `"assets": [
>       "assets",
>       "assets/images/favicon.ico",
>       ".htaccess"
>     ],`

Comment: I am not using angular-cli.json file.
How can include htaccess into webpack.config.js file?

Comment: so this is not _angular_ question ;)
just search for `webpack copy file`...
also mark this anser as accepted.

Comment: @gaurav .. can you post the solution here?

Answer (score 13):

By having `.htaccess` outside the `src`, you'll most likely to get the following error,

> An unhandled exception occurred: The .htaccess asset path must start with the project source root.

The corrected approach is this,

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  "src/.htaccess"
],
...
```

Make sure to put your `.htaccess` file under `src`.

[image]

With the above settings, when you run your `build`, you'll get the `.htaccess` inside the `dist`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is very useful :)

Comment: @MhdSaleh No worries :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also copy files to `dist` folder after build by defining your build commands in `package.json` on key `scripts` e.g.

```
"buildProd": "ng build --prod  && cp ./.htaccess ./dist/project-name/.htaccess",
```

copy file `.htaccess` to main projet folder (not src) and run build command by `npm run buildProd` to create `dist`.

This approach not introduce server files to angular build step (it do it "outside").

Answer (score 0):

I have application on Angular 12 and nothing worked for me except the below solution, I have my hosting at GoDaddy Linux server.
I was getting 404 on refresh of page and below code resolved my error

put below code in .htaccess file and place your file in project folder(top level along with angular.json file) not in src or somewhere else

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

then run the below command in terminal

```
ng build --prod
```

then run the below command in terminal to copy your .htaccess file in dist/projectName folder

```
cp ./.htaccess ./dist/projectName folder/.htaccess
```

I hope that this solution helps someone like me.