# on refreshing page , not found error, need solution without using #

Tags: angular9

I have a angular 9 project. I deployed it to server. On server when I refresh angular app, it shows error :

**Error:**

**start**

Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

**end**

**we are using below for development**

server : Apache

frontend : angular

backend : nodejs

I did not understand what happened. I tried this solution

[link to solution what I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907736/refreshing-the-page-results-in-404-error-angular-6/50910433)

but We don't want # in over url. with out #, we want solution.
please suggest proper solution.
thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your app like this using angular cli.

```
ng build --prod --base-href /<project_name>/
```

Try with this in `.htaccess` one and let me know as It works for me.

> Put .htaccess in src folder (final path for is src/.htaccess) and give the file path in angular.json inside "assets"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62107894/9739044)

Comment: thank you for your response.
where to put .htaccess file....?

Comment: Follow this `https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887726/9739044`

Comment: thanks sibabrat, I applied and tested on server and working fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a `.htaccess` file on the root of the deployed project i.e. along with `index.html`. Below is the code to be written in the above file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html
# to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Please see the below image -

[image]